# Is it possible to attach commands to a programme I want to run?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, execute-command, pcsx2

UBUNTU 20.04

I have PCSX2 but in order for it to run correctly I need to open the terminal and run:

```
vblank_mode=0 /usr/games/PCSX2-linux.sh
```

having to do this every time is a bit of an annoyance so is it possible to attach this command to PCSX2 so when it runs it automatically applies this fix?

PS: brand new to ubuntu so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing it.

For instance you can edit the `PCSX2-linux.sh` file and add there

```
export vblank_mode=0
```

after the shebang.

The first 2 lines should look this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
export vblank_mode=0
```

Another way is to add `vblank_mode=0` to the `Exec=` line of the `.desktop` file.

Comment: I added it so it looks like: #!export vblank_mode=0/bin/sh but it does not seem to work? am I making an error?

Comment: Why did you add `#!`? The first line should be something like `#!/bin/sh`. After this line add `export vblank_mode=0` without any additions. You added it between `#!` and `/bin/sh`.